# Remove XP from dual boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot

How do I completly remove XP from my pc. I currently have a dual boot with XP and Windows 7. Since installing Windows 7, I have never used XP. Can I remove it without causing problems with Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to stop the message at startup asking which OS you want to boot to, you can change the Startup & Recovery to have Windows 7 as the default and uncheck the "Time to display list of operating system" or set the display time to 0.  That way you will never be asked which OS you want to boot to, the computer will just boot into Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you had XP installed on the machine and then added Windows 7, installing on an extra partition or disk. If so, then your machine will be booting off the XP installation. If you just get rid of your XP partition you will have to repair the boot system.

If your two Windows installations are on separate disks, then I would just boot into Windows 7, run `msconfig` and delete the boot entry for Windows XP. You can then delete the stuff on the Windows XP partition, leaving only the stuff needed to boot (essentially C:\bootmgr and C:\Boot which Windows 7 will try to hide from you anyway) and anything you need to keep.  This leaves you with your exising Windows 7 installation and the space used by Windows XP as a (more or less) empty disk .

If the two Windows partitions are on the same disk then the easiest thing is to do as above.

You could also delete the XP partition and add the space freed to the Windows 7 partition. To do the this, you need to migrate the boot system from the XP partition to the Windows 7 partition.

Either make the Windows 7 partition `active`, boot from the Windows 7 DVD and follow the prompts to "startup repair" or use [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/63646/moving-windows-7-boot-files-bootmgr-bootsect-bak-boot-directory-to-different) to move the boot system to the Windows 7 partition.

Once you are booting off the Windows 7 partition, you can delete the XP partition and expand the Windows 7 one using Windows' built in disk manager.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a LiveCD that has a partitioning program on it, like [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).

You can remove the partition and try expanding the Windows 7 partition. Just make sure, you do a complete backup of your sensitive data that's currently on your Windows 7 installation.

Check how Windows 7 is installed. sometimes, you'll have a boot partition, but that not always the case.

To modify the boot menu, use a BCD editor as described [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5110-dual-boot-change-os-name-windows-boot-manager.html).

Answer (score 0):

See this excellent guide

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=1751

.

Answer (score 0):

Is the xp on an extra partition? I think so. 
Go to the Disk Manager in Win7 and delete the partition. 
Now you can create a new one and use the free space.Make sure you copied all your important data from this partition. 
If you want a second partition for data you dont need a boot cd. If you want to expand the size of the windows 7 partition you need a boot cd, see polemon's post.