# How to boot directly into Vista and Windows 8 from Grub without the Microsoft boot manager?

Tags: multi-boot, windows-8-preview, bootloader, grub2

I have Vista and Windows 8 installed each on a primary partition and use Grub as boot manager. The problem is that Grub can no longer directly boot into Vista after the installation of Windows 8, as Windows 8 overwrites the Vista boot manager with it's own, which on top has the nasty habit of requiring an additional reboot before going into Vista (i.e. Grub -> WindowsBoot -> reboot -> Grub again -> Vista). Restoring the Vista boot manager isn't hard, but it wouldn't help, as the Windows 8 partition itself isn't bootable on it's own.

How can I configure it so that I can boot right into Vista and Windows 8 from Grub without having to use the Windows boot manager?

Edit: To clarify it a bit, what I want is simply: Vista bootmgr on the Vista partition, Windows 8 bootmgr on the Windows 8 partition and Grub in the MBR to select which one to boot.

Edit2: A partial answer can be found at:

- [How do I move the Windows 7 Boot Files (bootmgr, ...) to a different drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/63646/how-do-i-move-the-windows-7-boot-files-bootmgr-to-a-different-drive)

With that I managed to get a somewhat working configuration (copied c:\boot over to drive e:, fudged around with `bcdedit.exe` to set some drives from c: to e:). Still have some remaining trouble such as Vista refusing to skip the boot menu automatically and Vista booting from the Windows 8 BCD and vice versa for some reason.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for Grub to directly boot a Windows volume. I believe Grub boots the Windows volume's bootloader, which then boots the Windows system. For what you want to work, you'd probably have to ensure that the Vista volume has the Vista bootloader, and the Windows 8 volume has the Windows 8 bootloader.

Comment: The problem isn't using the Windows bootloader itself, that's fine, but not being able to generate separate Grub entries for both Windows partitions, as the Windows 8 partition isn't bootable by default and the Vista partition get's the annoying Windows 8 bootloader. There should be some bcdedit/bootsect magic to fix that and make the Win8 partition bootable itself and restore the Vista bootloader to the Vista partition, just haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: I think this is to do with Windows 8 changing the game completely with its UEFI implementation.

Comment: It's not really Windows 8 specific, as the whole BCD stuff seems to work pretty much the same as in Vista and the same problems would probably happen just the same with Windows 7 or two copies of Vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step, install Vista, Windows 8 and Linux as usual. Windows 8 will install it's boot manager on the Vista partition, thus destroying the Vista bootloader.

Second step, copy the `C:\Boot\` directory from the Vista to the Windows 8 partition, so the Windows 8 boot loader is where it belongs. This might need to be done from within Linux or the Windows recovery console, as Windows keeps a lock on some of the files.

Third step, use bcdedit to let the Windows 8 boot manager point to the Windows 8 partition, instead of the Vista one:

```
bcdedit.exe /store E:\boot\bcd /set {bootmgr} device partition=E:
```

This might need to be done from a Windows Installation disc in recovery mode.

Fourth step, boot with the Windows recovery disc and let it repair the Windows Vista boot or do it manually with:

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

The Windows Vista and Windows 8 boot loaders should now be each on their own partition where they belong.

To get rid of the boot menu one has to delete the Windows 8 menu entries from the Vista BCD and the Vista entry from the Windows 8 BCD, as `timeout 0` and `displaybootmenu No` don't seem to work on their own. This can be done easily with EasyBCD.

Another thing to keep in mind, most of the Windows boot fix tools will work only on the partition with the boot flag set and do not allow to operate on a different partition. Thus one needs to ensure with `cfdisk` that the boot flag is set for the proper partition. This caused most of my confusion in the process, as even tools like EasyBCD would constantly try to operate on the wrong drive (i.e. the Windows 8 partition was marked bootable, needed to reset that to the first partition).

If everything is done `update-grub` should properly detect both Windows partitions and be able to boot into each directly without the Windows boot menu.

Comment: Took me a bit to get it to work right (using Windows 7, Windows 8, and Ubuntu), but following the instructions in this post got it working smoothly. EasyBCD allows you to edit BCD files on other partitions, so the boot flag wasn't a big deal. It also took a while, cause booting off of windows disks and ubuntu install jump drives took 5-10 minutes per reboot, but wasn't much actual effort. I would +2 this post if I could.